# Insertion in a Binary search tree not working

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am new in programming and I was trying insertion in a binary search tree program.My code is:

```
struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key)
{
   if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);
   if (key < node->key)
    node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
   if (key > node->key)
    node->right = insert(node->right, key);
   return node;
}
```

But its not producing correct output. The solution given is:

```
struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key)
{
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    return node;
}
```

How is `else` going to affect the insertion ?

Comment: "Not working" and "not producing correct output" are terrible problem descriptions. Elaborate, *how* does it not work? What is the *actual* and *expected* "output"? Have you tried to debug your code? And please [learn about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should read about [mutual exclusivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusivity)

Comment: Always debug your code manually yourself before asking it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to get rid of these kind of problem always dry run your code yourself.

```
 struct Node* insert(struct Node* node, int key)
  {
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);
    if (key < node->key) // Stmt 1
     node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    if (key > node->key) //Stmt 2
     node->right = insert(node->right, key);
    return node;
  }
```

Here you need to understand recursion correctly. In your code the compiler will go for both stmt1 and stmt2.

Suppose the compiler is executing the recursion part of `stmt1` 3 times for recursive left nodes, then it will execute `stmt2` each time for each right node. But if you use `else` in `stmt2` then your code will not execute `stmt2` for recursion part of stmt1.  It will execute only one of `stmt1` or `stmt2` if you use `else`.

Comment: The conditions ought to be mutually exclusive, though. If `key < node->key`, then not `key > node->key`, and the recursive call shouldn't change either `key` or `node->key` unless `newNode` does strange things.

Comment: Do you mean "it will execute stmt2 each time for each *right* node"

Comment: sorry for late reply...and yes i mean for a particular node if we use else than only one of stmt1 or stmt2 execute but if we do not use else it will execute stmt2 for each right node of that particular node...

Comment: Secondly, the point 0x499602D2 was trying to make was that your answer appears to be wrong, in the place he/she has indicated. Would you [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35176401/edit) please, to correct it? Thank you.

Comment: @halfer Yes,the code i have shown in my answer is incorrect and i have explained what is wrong in that code..it will be correct after we use else in stmt2...So the correct code is the second code given in the question...and if my answer is incorrect please explain the problem....If we use else ...then it will not execute stmt2 each time for each right node..i have also tried it on compiler..it is producing correct output...

Comment: I have corrected the text to read "then it will execute stmt2 each time for each **right** node", as per my comments. Please change it back if this is wrong.